# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Chapter 9: Missing template update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I just finished [Section 9.3 - Unsuccessful Edits](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users.html#sec-unsuccessful_edits) of Michael Hartl's book Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I've been trying for hours to figure out why I can't get the test to pass that checks for an unsuccessful edit.

Here is the code I've added for the chapter:

**spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
     let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) } 

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }
    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content("Name can't be blank") }
        it { should have_content("Email can't be blank") }
        it { should have_content("Email is invalid") }
        it { should have_content("Password can't be blank") }
        it { should have_content("Password is too short") }
        it { should have_content("Password confirmation can't be blank") }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/support/utilities.rb:**

```
include ApplicationHelper

def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end

def valid_signin(user)
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
end

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/users_controllers.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end  
end
```

**app/models/users.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { self.email.downcase! }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  # Validate that a name is not blank and is no longer than50 characters
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  # Validate that an email address is not blank, contains a valid pattern, and 
  # is not already in the database
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, 
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } 

  #Validate the password is there and is at least 6 characters
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, on: :create
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create

  # Everything below this private is only visibile to this user model
  private

    # Creates a remember token for the user (not a local variable)
    # Used to keep a user login active indefinitely after sign in
    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

**app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**app/views/users/edit.html.erb:**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm receiving the following errors:

```
Failures:

  1) User pages edit with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Save changes" }
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template users/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/cbachich/Development/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:79:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.65 seconds
67 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81 # User pages edit with invalid information
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your controller doesn't do anything in the case of a successful user update, which means Rails is going to render the users/update view. Since you don't have this view, that's the error you see. Saverio's note is good - you should add a `redirect_to` to get to the show action. That'll get rid of this error.

But there's a bigger problem. Why is your controller taking the successful update path when you expect it to take the fail path and render the edit view?

Based on my experience, the edit page fills in the email and email but leaves the passwords blank. You're expecting the update to fail because there are no passwords, but the update succeeds. Why? If you look at the model, your password validations are only `on: :create`. This means these validations aren't performed on the update. You're expecting the password validations to be performed on the update, but they aren't, which is why the edit succeeds instead of fails.

If you update the model to perform those validations for the create and update actions (probably something like `on: { :create, :update }` ), you should be back in business. Your update with invalid data will fail like it should.

Comment: This actually sounds like it could be my problem. I'll test it tonight when I get home.

Comment: This worked. I guess the default is on create and update, so I just removed that from the user model and the test passed. Thanks Kyle!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a template for the UsersController's update action?

It should be in `app/view/users/update.html.erb`.

On a side note, normally one ends up redirecting on a successful update, so you may not need that template, if you add a proper `redirect_to` in the update action.

Comment: I do not have the update template but I don't think I need it for this test. I haven't got to the point where I'm testing a successful edit. So based on the users controller it "should" render an edit. Or at least that's how I'm interpretting the code.

Comment: The error specifically complains about that template is missing. What leads you to think that it's not the case?

Comment: The test that is failing is suppose to check for invalid data being submitted. So it shouldn't be directed toward an update page, it should be redirected to the edit page since it shouldn't pass authentication. I agree that the error specifically is it missing the template, but this test shouldn't care about the update template. Not yet at least.

Answer (score 0):

The following block

```
    describe "edit" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

      describe "page" do
        it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
        it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
      end

      describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Save changes" }

        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end
```

Creates a @user and without changing anything in the form clicks the save button, therefore it does send all the required field content and it is handled as a successful update in the corresponding controller.

If you change the last block with

```
describe "with invalid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Name", with: " "
      click_button "Save changes"
    end

    it { should have_content('error') }
  end
```

then the name field will be empty and the operation will be handled as an unsuccessful update and fall in the else block to render 'edit'.